# Use RangeWidget on Tiff Image using visAd Library

Tags: tiff

Is it possible to use rangeWidget on Tiff images using visad.util.RangeWidget?

I have used RangeWidget on ".nc" files.
And the use of RangeWidget is given here:( Eg: 2.10 , 2.11 )

```
http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~billh/tutorial/s2/Section2.html
```

Comment: Change on rages dose not affect on the tiff image I've plotted using visAD library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible the same way given in example, It was a logical error.
I was rerendering an image so changes are not displayed.